# Label for Quota on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How can be quota set on Kubernetes using label selector like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: thequota-for-restrictedsoftware
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "3"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      restricted: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent some time digging in the documentation and trying to find the answer to your question, and I'm not 100% sure, but it is not possible at this moment in the way you need it.

Comment: how about now? 5 Years later ... is this possible?

Comment: still no. the k8s open source community seems to have rejected the idea : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/110065